# Downloading rss content in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib2

I am creating a python application where I am downloading a list of rss content from internet. I am having a list of 10 url's which I need to download.

I am using the urllib2 library provided by python. The code I am using is:

```
for url in urls:
    rssObject = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    data = rssObject.read()
    with open(self.SERVER_PATH+"\\feeds\\"+str(feedID)+str(extension), "w") as requiredData:
        requiredData.write(str(data))
    requiredData.close()
```

Here the first url is downloaded but while downloading the next url I get an error:

```
<urlopen error [Errno 66] unknown>
```

Is there any event which can notify me for the completion of the downloading of the first URL? Or is there any other way with the help of which I can avoid this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

*Is there any event which can notify me for the completion of the downloading of the first URL?*

The raising of the Exception is notification that the URL cannot be downloaded.

*Or is there any other way with the help of which I can avoid this issue?*

Yes, you can catch the exception.

```
try:
    rssObject = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    data = rssObject.read()
except URLError:
    # do stuff which handles the error
```

I'm not perfectly sure that's the error you need to catch, but hopefully you have the skills to work out exactly what to catch (if it's not URLError).

Comment: Was about to answer pretty much the same thing. I think he copied the error message but without the exception name that is also printed in the traceback. The exception is pretty likely `URLError` as you said, so your code should catch it. As for the 66, I still haven't found what that error is.

Comment: @Gaurang: You could try printing the exception's `reason` attribute, if you wanted to know why this is happening.

Comment: I have also searched about it on google but no info is available about error 66. Plus the description shown in the error shows unknown.

Comment: When I am printing the reason attribute it prints:  [Errno 66] unknown

Comment: I have tried catching the URLError in exception. It prints the same error which I have specified in my question.

Comment: You could try seeing if it happens randomly or with some URLs. If it happens randomly the problem is likely at your end; maybe a problem with your connection. If it happens with some URLs you can see what's peculiar about them.

Comment: It happens randomly. Thats what I am asking. Is there any completed event for urllib2.urlopen?

Comment: If it happens randomly, you can retry the `urlopen()` when an error occurs.

Comment: @Gaurang the only `completed` event you're going to get is when you hit the end of the read: an EOFError.  But I dare suggest that actually using EOFError would be unpythonic; when the read returns it is complete.

Answer (score 0):

As a follow-up to John Mee's answer, and after reading your comments, you can try something like the following:

```
def complete_urlopen(url):
    complete = False
    while not complete:
        try:
            obj = urllib2.urlopen(url)
            complete = True
        except URLError, e:
            pass
    return obj.read()
```

And then use it by replacing:

```
rssObject = urllib2.urlopen(url)
data = rssObject.read()
```

with:

```
data = complete_urlopen(url)
```

Be aware that this code assumes that the `urlopen()` will eventually succeed. If it never does, your process will hang in that `while` loop forever. A more sophisticated version of this could contemplate a max number of iterations, such that when they're reached, the process exits.